# Azure Data Factory Counting number of Files in Folder

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am attempting to determine if a folder is empty.

My current method involves using a GetMeta shape and running the following to set a Boolean.

**@greater(length(activity('Is Staging Folder Empty').output.childItems), 0)**

This works great when files are present.

When the folder is empty (a state I want to test for) I get

"The required Blob is missing".

Can I trap this condition?

What alternatives are there to determine if a folder is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reproduced the above and got same error.

[image]

This error occurs when the folder is empty, and the **source is a Blob storage**. You can see it is working fine for me when the Source is ADLS.

[image]

for sample I have used set variable.

[image]

inside false of if.

[image]

**if folder is empty:**

[image]

> Can I trap this condition?
>
> What alternatives are there to determine if a folder is empty?

One alternative can be to use ADLS instead of Blob storage as source.

**(or)**

You can do like below, if you want to avoid this error with Blob storage as source. Give an **if activity** for the **failure of Get Meta** and check the error in the expression.

```
@startswith(string(activity('Get Metadata1').error.message), 'The required Blob is missing')
```

[image]

**In True activities (required error and folder is empty)** I have used set variable for demo.

[image]

**In False activities (If any other error apart from the above occurs) use Fail activity** to fail the pipeline.

**Fail Message:**    `@string(activity('Get Metadata1').error.message)`

[image]

**For success of Get Meta activity, there is no need to check the count of child Items** because Get Meta data fails if the folder is empty. So, on success Go with your activities flow.

Comment: Thanks, that does work, I am guessing I will have to live with the error still occurring and being logged. As this is a form of try catch.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be

Blob:
[image]

Dataset :
[image]

where test is the container and test is the folder inside the container which I am trying to scan (Which ideally doesnt exist as seen above)

Use get meta data activity to check if the folder exists :
[image]

[image]

If false, exit else count for the files